# How to read api from mongoose using React

Tags: reactjs, api, express, mongoose

I'm trying to read data from my rest api from mongodb. However I can't get react to read the data from it. Here is my code. I can pull from other API but not from my custom. I've tried changing the json.data but it didn't work.

```js
import React from "react";

const url = "http://localhost:27017/projects";

export default class list extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      projects: []
    };
  }

  fetchData() {
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => this.setState({ projects: json.data }));
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 style={{ fontWeight: "1" }}>Project List</h1>
        <ul>
          {this.state.projects.map(s => (
            <li>{s.sId}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I think there is a problem with how I setup my api as well. Please take a look. And yes I can get the api through my postman.

```js
var app = require("express")();
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.json());

//create a connection to database
mongoose.connect("THE URL HERE");

//define a "table" structure
var ProjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  sId: String,
  sName: String,
  sYear: String,
  cId: String,
  cName: String,
  sem: String,
  aName: String,
  aDes: String,
  aPer: String,
  tech: String,
  scope: String,
  des: String,
  company: String,
  app: String,
  photoURL: String
});

var Project = mongoose.model("Project", ProjectSchema);

app.get("/projects", function(req, res) {
  Project.find({}, function(err, projects) {
    res.send(projects);
  });
});

app.post("/projects", function(req, res) {
  Project.create(req.body, function(err, project) {
    res.send(project);
  });
});

app.delete("/projects/:id", function(req, res) {
  Project.deleteOne({ sId: req.params.id }, function(err, result) {
    res.send(result);
  });
});

app.put("/projects/", function(req, res) {
  Project.findOneAndUpdate(
    { sId: req.body.sId },
    { sName: req.body.sName },
    function(err, result) {
      res.send(result);
    }
  );
});

app.get("/projects/search/:keyword", function(req, res) {
  Project.find({ sId: req.params.keyword }, function(err, result) {
    res.send(result);
  });
});

app.listen(27017);
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally we use componentDidMount to fetch data from apis.
The best place to make calls to fetch data is within componentDidMount(). componentDidMount() is only called once, on the client, compared to componentWillMount() which is called twice, once to the server and once on the client. It is called after the initial render when the client received data from the server and before the data is displayed in the browser.